# How to fix highstock flags on the top?

Tags: highcharts

I want to place highstock flags on the top of the chart. Is it possible?[image: move flags on the top]

Comment: Maybe instead of flags you may use renderer.label method? This will give you a possibility to plot your labels where you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ut1jmhz1/